# After installing ubuntu in dual boot with windows, now windows wont start

Tags: dual-boot, windows

So that is the repair boot tool report about my issue, so i hope you will help me guys.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Tc7qs3QNwx/

More info.
So i used chatgpt before and some others online tools so it see i must have a file /esp/efi/microsoft/ so i cant see the microsoft file, as i understand the boot windows file must be in this folder.

- Another stuff, i didnt see windows in where i must make the choose and chatgpt advice me to edit this file sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
  and add this into it
  menuentry "Windows 7" {
  insmod ntfs
  set root=(hd0,1)
  drivemap -s (hd0) ($root)
  ntldr /bootmgr
  }

WHen i do that, it now show me the windows in when i click on it shot me that hd0,1 not found.

So i see some reply i will try and see if i can resolve this issue. another update i install a virtual machine in the ubuntu i thought that i can access my old windows file into it but i cant.

Another Update i followed to rebuild bcd also with these commands
bootrec.exe /FixMbr  successfull
bootrec.exe /FixBoot successfull
bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd  After scaning windows disk installation ask to press Y, and it show me the requested system device cannot be found.

As requested that is my gparted screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYzJ8.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include everything in the question if possible. When I try the link I get "You need to be logged in to view this paste." If this is text, copy&paste it into the question and format it as a code block, e.g. by inserting 3 tilde characters `~~~` or 3 backticks as separate lines before and after the code.

Comment: Windows is in legacy mode, Ubuntu should be booted and installed in legacy too.  How the ubuntu install media boots depends upon machine settings, set it to legacy before UEFI.

Comment: You need to first move boot flag from the ESP, sda7 back to sda1, if sda1 is or was Windows boot partition. Windows has to see a NTFS partition with boot flag to make repairs.

Comment: @ubfan1 when i put it in legacy mode i cant even start the ubuntu and it show me boot device not found. Please install an operating system on your hard drive.

Comment: @oldfred how to move it back ?

Comment: With the gdisk or fdisk partition utility, first select x for expert mode, then ? or m for help and see that "a" (gdisk attributes) or "A" (fdisk toggle boot flag) gives you the ability to turn on or off the boot flag on a partition. Save results.  Ensure your machine is set to legacy boot, and Windows should boot (its bootloader is still in the MBR).  Installing grub from grub-pc (not the grub-efi package) should include a legacy Windows in the grub menu.

Comment: @ubfan1 hello, so i followed your advice, when i restart it stuck on hp logo screen and dont move there.

Answer (score 0):

reboot by windows USB flash drive, select repair and fix boot or select boot directly to windows from the hared disk. after that when you login to windwas use easybcd to put windows bootloader in the right place. restart the pc by boot-repair to put ubuntu and windows in the boot menu.
[image]

Comment: Hello many thx, so i follow your advice, when i see it but when i choose it show me press any key to continue when i do, it return to the screen where i will choose the Os again.

Comment: @carlo i edited my answer becuase grml can not play windows iso fle

Comment: @Taalat Etman  So i follow and it still give me the same error, like when i put on uefi mode, it only give me to choose ubuntu and when i put in legacy mode it told me no os found on hard drive. btw no way if you can try to help me thru teamviewver or anydesk ?

Comment: you mean fix it in command, or where to select boot directly to windows. Btw have a way to help me via teamviewer ?

Comment: I mean continue exit and continue with win 10 if you can do it you can add windows bootloader by easybcd. look to my answer I added imag.

Comment: Hello, so it didnt give me the option to choose continue to windows 10. this screen only show me turn off and troubleshoot options.

Comment: can you put image about your partitions from gparted

Comment: if you delete system reserved partition you have to rebuild it https://www.diskpart.com/articles/system-reserved-partition-missing-3889.html

Comment: Hello, so i edit the main post with the gparted picture.

Comment: @carlo your system reserved  partition look good please use this link to know how to fix windows boot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/windows-boot-issues-troubleshooting

Comment: thx, it a lot of process i will check it out

Comment: thanks you all for take care of my case, so i give up, i cant recover either my data and my windows.